# My base64 image returns in a different format after being called from a database

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, base64

I'm using a mySQL database to store images in base64 format, when I retrieve the image from the database it returns the format below. It's not what I inserted into the database and doesn't work with the functions I wish to use the base64 code in. I don't know what it returns like this, or how to fix it. It'd be amazing if someone could tell me what is going on, Thank you!

get and post request in Node.js which handle the DB transactions:

```
    router.get('/:image', (req, res, next) => {
        var values = [
            [req.params.image]
        ];
        var sql = "SELECT image FROM images WHERE name = ? " ;

        connection.query(sql, [values], function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("image got " + JSON.stringify(result));
            res.send(result);
        });

});



router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.name);
    const imageJSON = {
        name: req.body.name,
        image: req.body.image
    };
    res.status(201).json({
        message: imageJSON
    });
        var sql = "INSERT INTO images (name, image) VALUES ?";
        //Make an array of values:
        var values = [
            [req.body.name, req.body.image]
        ];
        console.log(req.body.name);
        connection.query(sql, [values], function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
        });
});
```

Outputted result:

```
[{"image":{"type":"Buffer","data":
[100,97,116,97,58,105,109,97,103,101,47,112,110,103,59,98,
    97,115,101,54,52,44,105,86,66,79,82,119,48,75,71,103,111,65,65,65,65,78,83,85,104,69,85,103,65,65,66,50,73,65,65,65,87,74,67,65,73,65,65,65,65,106,82,48,65,56,65,65,65,65,67,88,66,73,87,88,77,65,65,67,52,106,65,65,65,117,73,119,70,52,112,84,57,50,65,65,65,75,84,50,108,68,81,49,66,81,97,71,57,48,98,51,78,111,98,51,65,103,83,85,78,68,73,72,66,121,98,50,90,112,98,71,85,65,65,72,106,97,110,86,78,110,86,70,80,112,70,106,51,51,51,118,82,67,83,52,105,65,108,69,116,118,85,104,85,73,73,70,74,67,105,52,65,85,107,83,89,113,73,81,107,81,83,111,103,104,111,100,107,86,85,99,69,82,82,85,85,69,71,56,105,103,105,65,79,79,106,111,67,77,70,86,69,115,68,73,111,75,50,65,102,107,73,97,75,79,103,54,79,73,105,115,114,55,52,88,117,106,97,57,97,56,57,43,98,78,47,114,88,88,80,117,101,115,56,53,50,122,122,119,102,65,67,65,121,87,83,68,78,82,78,89,65,77,113,85,73,101,69,101,67,68,120,56,84,71,52,101,81,117,81,73,69,75,74,72,65,65,69,65,105,122,90,67,70,122,47,83,77,66,65,80,104,43,80,68,119,114,73,115,65,72,118,103,65,66,101,78,77,76,67,65,68,65,84,90,118,65,77,66,121,72,47,119,47,113,81,112,108,99,65,89,67,69,65,99,66,48,107,84,104,76,67,73,65,85,65,69,66,54,106,107,75,109,65,69,66,71,65,89,67,100,109,67,90,84,65,75,65,69,65,71,68,76,89,50,76,106,65,70,65,116,65,71,65,110,102,43,98,84,65,73,67,100,43,74,108,55,65,81,66,98,108,67,69,86,65,97,67,82,65,67,65,84,90,89,104,69,65,71,103,55,65,75,122,80,86,111,112,70,65,70,103,119,65,66,82,109,83,56,81,53,65,78,103,116,65,68,66,74,86,50,90,73,65,76,67,51,65,77,68,79,69,65,117...
```

Inserted code:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB2IAAAWJCAIAAAAjR0A8AAAACXBIWXMAAC4jAAAuIwF4pT92AAAKT2lDQ1BQaG90b3Nob3AgSUNDIHByb2ZpbGUAAHjanVNnVFPpFj333vRCS4iAlEtvUhUIIFJCi4AUkSYqIQkQSoghodkVUcERRUUEG8igiAOOjoCMFVEsDIoK2AfkIaKOg6OIisr74Xuja9a89+bN/rXXPues852zzwfACAyWSDNRNYAMqUIeEeCDx8TG4eQuQIEKJHAAEAizZCFz/SMBAPh+PDwrIsAHvgABeNMLCADATZvAMByH/w/qQplcAYCEAcB0kThLCIAUAEB6jkKmAEBGAYCdmCZTAKAEAGDLY2LjAFAtAGAnf+bTAICd+Jl7AQBblCEVAaCRACATZYhEAGg7AKzPVopFAFgwABRmS8Q5ANgtADBJV2ZIALC3AMDOEAuyAAgMADBRiIUpAAR7AGDIIyN4AISZABRG8lc88SuuEOcqAAB4mbI8uSQ5RYFbCC1xB1dXLh4ozkkXKxQ2YQJhmkAuwnmZGTKBNA/g88wAAKCRFRHgg/P9eM4Ors7ONo62Dl8t6r8G/yJiYuP+5c+rcEAAAOF0ftH+LC+zGoA7BoBt/qIl7gRoXgugdfeLZrIPQLUAoOnaV/Nw+H48PEWhkLnZ2eXk5NhKxEJbYcpXff5nwl/AV/1s+X48/Pf14L7iJIEyXYFHBPjgwsz0TKUcz5IJhGLc5o9H/LcL//wd0yLESWK5WCoU41EScY5EmozzMqUiiUKSKcUl0v9k4t8s+wM+3zUAsGo+AXuRLahdYwP2SycQWHTA4vcAAPK7b8HUKAgDgGiD4c93/+8//UegJQCAZkmScQAAXkQkLlTKsz/HCAAARKCBKrBBG/TBGCzABhzBBdzBC/xgNoRCJMTCQhBCCmSAHHJgKayCQiiGzbAdKmAv1EAdNMBRaIaTcA4uwl…
```

Comment: "It's not what I inserted" - Show your insert statement.

Comment: ive edited there.

Comment: What language is this in? Where's the insert/retrieval code?

Comment: I do the insert/retrieval on a Node.js server

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had my database set so that images were stored as blobs, so storing a base64 code in a blob is going to return a binary output. I've just changed it to a LONGTEXT data type.